# OpenLayers plugin not loading in QGIS 2.16.3 in OS X.

Tags: qgis-openlayers-plugin

I get this error whenever I try to open any map through OpenLayers plugin. Please help! I have tried searching online for the solution but could not find any or rather could not figure out much.

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @SakshiRana! Try using the **QuickMapServices** plugin instead.

Comment: I would recommend QuickMapServices, as @Joseph suggests.  However, if you want to get the OpenLayers plugin working, I have had success with simply uninstalling and then re-installing the plugin.